# Differences in processing DejaVu Serif between LuaTeX and XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex

I'm trying to set a heading in DejaVu Serif Condensed Bold. Simplified, here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif Condensed}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\bfseries\huge Curriculum Vitæ
\end{document}
```

On processing with XeLaTeX, I get this:

[image: XeTeX output]

while with LuaLaTeX, this:

[image: LuaTeX output]

which is the regular series. This is backed up by the log. XeLaTeX shows no warnings, but LuaLaTeX gives this:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/DejaVuSerifCondensed(0)/bx/n'
>   undefined using`EU2/DejaVuSerifCondensed(0)/m/n' instead on input li

What's going on here?

For reference, TeXLive 2012 updated to final version, Windows 7

---

It occurred to me that I might have different fonts in the Windows system font folder and in the texmf-dist tree. Not so - the two folders have identical copies of the fonts.

Comment: same here with cygwin texlive 2012

Comment: The warning means that `luaotfload` couldn’t find the bold font when `fontspec` asked for it. I can reproduce it with TeX Live 2013 as well, so it is a `luaotfload` bug and should be reported.

Comment: I can reproduce it too. As a workaround you can setup the bold font directly: `\setmainfont[BoldFont=DejaVu Serif Condensed Bold]{DejaVu Serif Condensed}`

Comment: Can’t reproduce it with the current luaotfload. Here, ``luaotfload-tool --find="DejaVu Serif Condensed"`` correctly resolves to ``DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf`` (in TL ``texmf`` tree). Consequently, the example code produces the same result with Luatex as with Xetex.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Would you like me to add an issue to your github tracker?

Comment: As you wish, @phg is the maintainer not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a hack to get the right fonts when LuaLaTeX is used, while the bug is being solved:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
  \setmainfont[
    BoldFont={* Bold},
    ItalicFont={* Italic},
    BoldItalicFont={* BoldItalic}
  ]{DejaVu Serif Condensed}
\else
  \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif Condensed}
\fi

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\huge

Curriculum Vitae

{\bfseries Curriculum Vitae}

{\itshape Curriculum Vitae}

{\bfseries\itshape Curriculum Vitae}

\end{document}
```

This is the result with LuaLaTeX

[image]

<sub>(I've changed `æ`, that I consider wrong, into `ae`, I hope you don't mind.)</sub>

Comment: I detected a similar problem. "DejaVu Serif" is resolved to "dejavuserifcondensed.ttf" instead of "dejavuserif.ttf". So setting main font to "DejaVu Serif" causes a very different line and page breaks between lualatex and xelatex. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @JLDiaz It seems that `luaotfload` matches the wrong font; indeed `luaotfload-tool --find="DejaVu Serif"` prints out `Resolved file name “DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf”`

Comment: @JLDiaz This seems a bug. Loading the font with `\setmainfont[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]{DejaVuSerif}` at least is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much for the workaround. I reported the bug in the [luaotfload bugtrack](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues?page=1&state=open).