# Selecting optical sizes for all fonts in a family

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, luaotfload

XeTeX and LuaTeX are able to assign optical sizes to fonts when they are provided. In those situations where XeTeX or LuaTex are unable to correctly assign optical sizes I am able to specify them but only for the regular font, not for italics, bold, or bold italics. I'm looking for a way to assign all of them.

The specific example I'm using is for Minion Pro and I know a package exists for it but I'm looking for a general solution I can apply as a regular user whenever something like this comes up again.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[openleft,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={MinionPro-It},BoldFont={MinionPro-Bold},BoldItalicFont={MinionPro-BoldIt}]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
Regular\\
\textit{Italic}\\
\textbf{Bold}\\
\textit{\textbf{Bold Italic}}\
{\tiny tiny}\\     
{\normalsize normal}\\ 
{\Large Large}\\       
{\LARGE LARGE}\\       
{\HUGE HUGE}\\         

{\tiny{
  \textit{tiny italic} \textbf{tiny bold} \textbf{\textit{tiny bold italic}}}}\\
{\Large{
\textit{Large italic} \textbf{Large bold} \textbf{\textit{Large bold italic}}}}\\
{\HUGE{
\textit{HUGE italic} \textbf{HUGE bold} \textbf{\textit{HUGE bold italic}}}}

\end{document}
```

Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX need the italic, bold, and bold italic fonts declared. After that XeLaTeX uses all the correct optical sizes for this example. LuaLaTeX does not use any of them (except as before for the regular font).

If you change the `\setmainfont` section to look like this:

```
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={MinionPro-It},BoldFont={MinionPro-Bold},BoldItalicFont={MinionPro-BoldIt},
SizeFeatures={ 
{Size={-8.4},OpticalSize=8},
{Size={8.4-13},OpticalSize=11},
{Size={13-19.9},OpticalSize=19},
{Size={19.9-},OpticalSize=72}}
]
{Minion Pro}
```

Then everything still works for XeLaTeX and now the optical sizes (Caption, Regular, SubHeader, Display) work with LuaLaTeX for the regular fonts but not for italics, bold, and bold italics.

I had thought that maybe something like:

```
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={MinionPro-It},BoldFont={MinionPro-Bold},BoldItalicFont={MinionPro-BoldIt},
SizeFeatures={ 
{Size={-8.4},OpticalSize=8,ItalicFont={MinionPro-ItCapt},
{Size={8.4-13},OpticalSize=11},
{Size={13-19.9},OpticalSize=19,ItalicFont={MinionPro-ItSubH},
{Size={19.9-},OpticalSize=72,ItalicFont={MinionPro-Disp}}} 
] 
{Minion Pro}
```

Would work (obviously filling in the bold and bold italic fonts and the other sizes) but that results in an error. I've tried several variations on that idea and nothing works. I keep reading over the fontspec and luaotfload manuals but can find nothing on how to do this thing specifically (I did find a reference to a "goodies" file for ConTeXt but was unable to figure out how to load it into a LuaLaTeX document).

**Update** Some more experimentation with Adobe fonts. I just did the same experiment with Garamond Premier Pro (also has optical sizes). And the results are similar. LuaLaTeX will just not load the Caption/Subheading/Display versions of Italic/Bold/Bold Italic though it handles the Regular font without even having to specify the optical sizes (thanks to a fix supplied when I asked a similar question before about Garamond specifically). XeLaTeX will but uses the SemiBoldItalic versions for the different optical sizes instead of just BoldItalic.

Comment: I don’t have Minion’s opticals but do have opticals for 3 other Adobe fonts by Robert Slimbach, and none requires specifying the italic, etc. I’d be surprised if a general solution exists: when a font has optical sizes but xe/luatex acts as if it didn’t, you’ve encountered a bug, and if the bug is in the font, well, each buggy font is buggy in its own way.  So you’d need to inspect the font and find a work-around (perhaps a feature file) for its peculiarities.

Comment: There are a couple of Adobe fonts w/ incorrect optical size information --- details should be on the XeTeX mailing list.

Comment: I see you've tried nesting the italic fonts inside the size specification; have you tried nesting the size specification inside the ItalicFeatures option?

Comment: @Thérèse I'm all for preparing a feature file. I'm not exactly sure what one is or how to go about doing it but I'm certainly willing to dig in and put in the effort if someone can point me in the right directions. Also, when I say I'm looking for a "general solution" I mean something ideally like the example I gave -- where I have to specify the fonts. This as opposed to there being a bug in luaotfload that requires hardcore coding. I want to be able to fix this on my own in the future (much like for many of the fonts on my system I have to specify the bold, italic, and bold italic fonts).

Comment: @WillAdams this font works fine with XeLaTeX, it's LuaLaTeX where the problem is. Would the XeTeX mailing list be able to help out in that situation?

Comment: @ChrisS I hadn't tried anything like that. In my experiments just now anything I added was interpreted as being part of the font name and resulted in an error (font not found). Do you have any specific ideas as to what specific syntax I might try? Part of the problem *appears* to be that there is not a `font` option within the `Size` field, just `Optical Size`. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: Search for “feature file” on this site and you’ll find some examples. Also see III.11 in the `fontspec` documentation. And if you have FontForge, you can inspect feature files (Element → Font Info → Lookups, right-click on any lookup, select Save Feature File or, for only one feature, Save Lookup).

Comment: This *may* be related to [Differences in processing DejaVu Serif between LuaTeX and XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119042/differences-in-processing-dejavu-serif-between-luatex-and-xetex)

Comment: @Thérèse there's a lot to go through, but before I dive in too deeply it appears that this kind of approach is more about changing the characteristics of a particular glyph or glyphs or which glyphs in a particular font will be used. My problem has more to do with the fact that LuaLaTeX is not loading the different fonts as per their optical sizes (i.e., these are different font files, not just alternate glyphs within one font).

Comment: Indeed, I fail to see how feature files can be of any help here. That is clearly a `luaotfload` bug and you should report it before looking for workarounds. But then I don’t understand why you have to select all font styles manually, something is deeply broken on your side.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I emailed the devs about 20 minutes ago, is there a better place to report the issue? I'm not sure if I understand your last sentence, I've spent the last couple of weeks going through some 100+ commercial fonts on my system and with many of them I have to set the ItalicFont (etc.) options. This is mainly the case when a font (like Minion and Garamond Premier) has many weights like Light, Extra Light, Medium, Semi-Bold, Extra Bold, Black, etc. If there're only four fonts in the family then XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are fine.

Comment: You can use the [issue tracker](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues).

Comment: @bfootdav I made a test file: https://bitbucket.org/phg/lua-la-tex-tests/src/tip/ltx-fontspec-optical-size-3.tex; Arno Pro and Garamond Premiere work fine here without extra settings, see these screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/7O8de. Can you test that file with your version of Minion Pro and report back?

Comment: @phg First, sorry I haven't responded to your email yet -- I'm trying to prepare a full report and it's not nearly done. Second, OMG your test file is much much more clever than mine. Third, and most importantly, as best as I can tell I get the same results. If you look closely there are a few issues (with Garamond, I don't have Arno). From `\scriptsize` to `\large` there are mistakes, e.g., at `\scriptsize` the regular and bold are at regular size and the italics are caption size. Also, if you use memoir w/extrafontsizes you should get the Display size when using /HUGE but you don't. cont.

Comment: @pgh I tried the file with Minion Pro and the results were similar -- some mistakes in selecting sizes and no Display size selected. If I specify the optical sizes for Garamond Premier Pro then the regular and bold use the correct optical sizes but at `\scriptsize \small and \normalsize` the italic and bold italic use the Caption size instead of regular. OK, and nuts, and I will answer my own question now, using Minion Pro while specifying the optical sizes works with all fonts at all sizes -- your testing method is just much easier to deal with and evaluate than mine and I made mistakes.

Comment: @bfootdav is this still an issue with version 2.4?

Comment: @phg I just tested with Garamond and Minion using your test file and it's much better. With Garamond all the optical sizes are correct but for `\scriptsize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, and `\large` the *italic* font is coming up as *medium italic*. The rest of the sizes are correct for italics and I don't see any other issues. I will check Minion Pro next.

Comment: So far Minion Pro looks perfect. I have a few other Adobe Premium Pro fonts on my system and I'll check them sometime today.

Comment: * for \scriptsize, \small, \normalsize, and \large the italic font is coming up as medium italic.* This is weird. In my tests it’s all fine. Have you deleted all cache files? What does ``luaotfload-tool --find="Garamond Premier Pro/i/s=8"`` resolve to (that’s italics for ``\scriptsize`` / caption)?

Comment: OK, so how does one go about deleting all one's cache files? When I run your command I get: luaotfload | resolve : Font "Garamond Premier Pro/i/s=8" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/share/fonts/custom/Garamond/GaramondPremrPro-ItCapt.otf"

Comment: When I run your command with s=10 I get: luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/share/fonts/custom/Garamond/GaramondPremrPro-MedIt.otf"

Which appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to specify the font for *each* feature. See section 5.1.2. of the fontspec manual.

A XeTeX MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
    UprightFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={ 
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-Capt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Regular},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-Subh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-Disp}
        },
    },
    BoldFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={ 
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Bold},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldDisp}
        },
    },
    ItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={ 
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-ItCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-It},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-ItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-ItDisp}
            },
    },
    BoldItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={ 
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldItCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-BoldIt},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldItDisp}
        },
    },
]
{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Regular\\
\textit{Italic}\\
\textbf{Bold}\\
\textit{\textbf{Bold Italic}}\\

\noindent
{\tiny tiny}\\     
{\normalsize normal, not \textbf{\textit{HUGE bold italic}}}\\ 
{\Large Large}\\       
{\LARGE LARGE}\\       
{\HUGE HUGE}\\         

\noindent
{\tiny{
  \textit{tiny italic} \textbf{tiny bold} \textbf{\textit{tiny bold italic}}}}\\
{\Large{
\textit{Large italic} \textbf{Large bold} \textbf{\textit{Large bold italic}}}}\\
{\HUGE{
\noindent
HUGE\\
\textit{HUGE italic}\\
\textbf{HUGE bold}\\
\textbf{\textit{HUGE bold italic}}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1! "... specify the font for each feature ..." came as such an unpleasant surprise that I actually checked it out (with XeLaTeX), and can confirm that the results are different. Surprising, too is that *all* the fonts are embedded in the pdf, even though some of them are not used (in the single-sizefeatures case). Hmm.

Comment: @Ludenticus, thanks for this. I could not for the life of me figure out the proper syntax for this. The manual doesn't make this very clear either. Regardless, this is huge for me.

Comment: I need to revise my earlier comment. I had checked SemiBold against Bold, and of course they were different! With XeTeX using the default choices for bold and italic, you don't need to specify the sizes for each feature -- a single set of size specifications works. (Though I use font names, rather than font *file*names). With LuaTeX, the results from the two idioms differ, and both differ from XeTeX. As I'm a XeTeX user, I don't plan to investigate the LuaTeX side further. (This year, anyway)

Answer (score 6):

With XeTeX you do *not* need multiple size declarations, and I believe you *should not* with LuaTeX. In what follows, I'll refer to @Ludenticus' solution as (1), and mine, which follows, as (2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1cm}{*}{1}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[%
    SizeFeatures={%
        {Size={-8.4},Font=* Caption},
        {Size={8.4-13},Font=*},
        {Size={13-19.9},Font=* Subhead},
        {Size={19.9-},Font=* Display}
    },
    BoldFont={* Bold},
    BoldItalicFont={* Bold Italic},
]
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\nonzeroparskip
\begin{document}
\noindent
Regular
\textit{Italic}
\textbf{Bold}
\textit{\textbf{Bold Italic}}\par

\noindent
{\tiny tiny}\par     
{\normalsize normal, not \textbf{\textit{HUGE bold italic}}}\par 
{\Large Large}\par       
{\LARGE LARGE}\par       
{\HUGE HUGE}\par         

\noindent
{\tiny{
  \textit{tiny italic} \textbf{tiny bold} \textbf{\textit{tiny bold italic}}}}\par
{\Large{
\textit{Large italic} \textbf{Large bold} \textbf{\textit{Large bold italic}}}}\par
{\HUGE{
\noindent
HUGE\par
\textit{HUGE italic}\par
\textbf{HUGE bold}\par
\textbf{\textit{HUGE bold italic}}}}

\end{document}
```

(1) and (2) processed with XeLaTeX produce visually identical PDFs (compared with `diffpdf`, option 'appearance'.

(1) and (2) processed with LuaLaTeX are different. The PDF from (1) has a full complement of embedded fonts (16), while (2) only has 10, the extra optical sizes being missing.

Notes:

- The default Bold association for Minion Pro is not 'bold', but 'semibold'. I assume this was what made you search for the parameters to change the two bold series.
- If you're happy with semibold, you can just omit the two Bold... lines altogether.
- I much prefer to use font *names* rather than font *filenames* -- it seems a lot less brittle (once you discover the right names!).

Comment: This appears to work for me in LuaTex. Thanks!