# Use optical sizes of fonts with fontspec for local files

Tags: xetex, fontsize, fontspec, luaotfload, ebgaramond

Now, this *is* the exact same question as [Is there a way to use different local font files for different font size in fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114223/is-there-a-way-to-use-different-local-font-files-for-different-font-size-in-font), but is is left without a solution. @WillRobertson answered in a comment more than two years ago that he would fix this in [`fontspec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), and I assume he has, since this is now addressed in sections 6.6 and 7.6 of the manual. But I still don't understand what I need to do in order to use the different fonts some font families provide for different optical sizes.

---

**EDIT:** See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267333/9077) to the original question for a solution.

---

Below is a MWE using [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/). I've tried a dozen or so variants of this, but they all result in errors, the most common of which (as below), is that it can't find a font called `EBGaramond.otf`.

In this example, I've placed the EB Garamond fonts in a subdirectory called `/fonts/`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
        Path = ./fonts/,
        Extension = .otf,
        SizeFeatures =
        {
            {Size = {10.1-},
                UprightFont = *12-Regular,
                ItalicFont = *12-Italic},
            {Size = {-10.1},
                UprightFont = *08-Regular,
                ItalicFont = *08-Italic}
        },
        SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps},
        Ligatures = {Common, TeX},
        Numbers = {Proportional, OldStyle}]
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc,dfont); reason: "File not found: ./fonts/EBGaramond.otf.".

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "EBGaramond" cannot be found.
```

Comment: To keep this place tidy and therefore easily searchable, it would seem better not to open a new, duplicate question, but to add a comment to the earlier one pinging Will Robertson.  But I don’t see that sections 6.6 and 7.6 of the manual address the problem.

Comment: @Thérèse The [`fontspec readme`](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/README) says for `v.2.4` that "`SizeFeatures` can now be nested inside `ItalicFeatures` (etc.) and behaves correctly. This has been a very long overdue bug!"

Comment: Sure, but that doesn’t address the problem with local files.

Comment: @Thérèse I see your point, but judging by the somewhat vague comment @WillRobertson gave, that bug is the reason why `SizeFeatures` didn't work for local files.

Comment: Then you should clarify your question.  If the problem is with local files only, then the question is a duplicate.  If it’s with fonts you’ve installed wherever your operating system wants them, then EB Garamond isn’t a good example, because it will use the right optical size automatically.  If the problem is with an installed font that doesn’t select the right size automatically, then there’s a good answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223633/7883.

Comment: @Thérèse I don't think my question needs clarification. It's about local files only, as stated. The reason I'm making this a new question is because when the original question was made, no solution was feasible, and Will said it was due to a bug. Now that bug is supposed to be fixed, but I still can't figure out how to do it. Maybe I should've edited the original question instead?

Comment: That’s not the bug that is supposed to be fixed.

Comment: @Thérèse I'm afraid we need to disagree on that. It finally dawned on me how to correctly read sections 6.6 and 7.6 of the fontspec manual, and I've added an [answer to the original question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267333/9077) to demonstrate how that bug fix enables the use of local font files for different optical sizes.