# MinionPro vs. FontPro

Tags: fonts, minionpro, installing-fonts

In the past I've used the [MinionPro scripts/packages](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/?lang=en), by Achim Blumensath, Andreas Bühmann and Michael Pedler, to install the Minion Pro font set. I have to do this once more on a new computer —a Mac this time— and I find that now there is an alternative set of scripts (and packages?), [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro), by Sebastian Schubert, forked off MinionPro.

> Can anyone tell me what are the differences between the two and which one the cool-yet-sensible guys are using these days?

Comment: Forks in software make me feel like a little kid being asked which of his recently divorced parents he wants to live with…

Comment: Well, the first half of your question feels like something more objective to ask. But even then, I'm not sure this is on topic on a site about LaTeX, since it seems to me you're asking about the fonts themselves, and not how to use them with Latex, correct?

Comment: I am asking about the procedure of the two to install the fonts —that's what both sets of packages & scripts do. I am not asking about the fonts themselves (notice that neither package includes the fonts, for example!)

Comment: Ah ok. My bad, I had misinterpreted. :D Still, the part *"which one the cool-yet-sensible guys are using these days?"* feels kinda subjective.

Comment: The cool and sensible guys make their choices based on informed judgement of the technical merits of things. That is as subjective as picking the correct screwdriver to screw a particular screw.

Comment: Not quite the same thing :P but I don't feel that strongly about it, so I'll wait for others to weigh in.

Comment: If you read the info about FontPro, it seems that it's intended as a refinement to the other scripts.

Comment: Just switch to Xe/LuaLaTeX and use the `fontspec` package to do `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}`.

Comment: @Henri, it seems that microtype support on those is not yet on par with that on pdftex.

Comment: @HenriMenke, on the other hand, I have tons of documents that I don't want to have to go through readapting to fontspec...  Does that «just use Xe/LuaLaTex» deal correctly with optical sizes and all?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, consult the section 7.6 »Optical font sizes« of the [`fontspec` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#subsection.7.6) for details or see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223915/10995) for a Minion Pro example.

Comment: @HenriMenke, that example does require extra set up for the optical sizes to be used. In that sense, «`\setmainfont{Minion Pro}`» does not do it :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Of course you have to specify which Opticals to use for which requested size.  How is `fontspec` supposed to know?  What `fontspec` does for you is select the correct Optical which you only have to setup *once.*

Comment: Well, the MinionPro package has an `opticals` option which does a sensible choice.